# Use awk to tarball specified files

Tags: awk

I have the following output from [`repo status`](http://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html#status):

```
project X/Y                  (*** NO BRANCH ***)
 --     A/B/c
 -m     D/E/f
project Z/                   (*** NO BRANCH ***)
 --     G/H/i
 -m     J/K/l
```

(lowercase letters are files, and uppercase are dirs)

The lines prefixed with `--` indicate newly added files. [`repo diff`](http://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html#diff) does not include these files, so I can't create a patch that includes *all* differences. So, I'll just create tarball of them.

**Q:** What script (e.g., `awk`, `perl`, or `python`) can I use to create a tarball of these files? The tarball should contain:

```
X/Y/A/B/c
Z/G/H/i
```

I'm thinking an `awk` script would be something like this (I'm not that familiar w/syntax):

```
awk {
    BEGIN curdir = '', filelist = []
    { 
        if ($0 == "project") {
            curdir = $1

        } else if ($0 == "--") {
            # insert file specified by $1 into tarball
        }
    }
}
```

Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. Here is some suggestion:

```
/^project/ {
    dir = $2
}

$1 == "--" {
    fullpath = dir $2 # space between dir and $2 means concatenation
    print fullpath
    # Do something with fullpath such as 
    # system("tar ...")
}
```

#### Discussion

- $1 is the first field (token) in a line, $2 is the second field, and so on
- $0 represent the whole record (line)
- Every time we see a line that starts with project, we save the directory, $2 to the variable *dir*
- Every time we see the first field of "--", we print out the directory, concatenated with the file name. In your case, insert command to archive the file here.